# Search random document "titles" between new lines on a large document

Tags: php, regex, sed, full-text-search, notepad++

How can I manage to count for a random "title" on a large (700mb) and "non-formatted" txt file?

The "title" is always in this format: `\n + random title + \n`. However multiple `\n` can appear consecutively.

I'm looking for a solution that uses Notepad++ or any other editor, just to count the results number (by using a regex expression for example), or a `sed` code to extract those titles, or any other solution in any language code (ie. Python, PHP, etc.)!

Example:

```
This is a random Title

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text

This is a another random Title

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text




This is a another another random Title

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text


This is a another another another random Title

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text
```

Comment: windows or linux line endings?

Comment: Linux ending lines

Comment: `grep '^Title$`. That was easy

Comment: @miken32 The name "Title" is just and indicative how it shown in the document. It doesn't have any tag "Title". I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match or count the number of titles as per your given text according to which a title will be followed by two newlines and preceded by at least two newlines.

```
(?:\r?\n\r?\n|\A\r?\n?)[^\r\n]+(\r?\n){2}
```

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jOFSvu/1)**

I have included `\r` optionally to make it work for Windows as well as Linux but if your line endings are Linux only, then you can remove `\r` from it.

Also, if you want to match and extract titles only, you can use grouping to capture the title, or use lookarounds to just match the title. Here is a grouping version of regex that captures the title in group1,

```
(?:\r?\n\r?\n|\A\r?\n?)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n){2}
```

**[Demo for matching title in group1](https://regex101.com/r/jOFSvu/2/)**

Also, verified in Notepad++ 7.6.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'NF==1{c++} END{print c+0}' file
4
```

The above simply prints the number of times you have a single non-blank line between any numbers of blank lines.